# History of the pullback corner notation

Tags: ct.category-theory, ho.history-overview, notation, pullback

Where/when did the convention originate of marking pullback (and/or pushout) squares by that little right-angle symbol in the corner?

[image: Pair of pullback squares; from Spivak, Category Theory for the Sciences; fair use for illustrative purposes of the use of this notation in the literature]

The earliest instance I’ve been able to find is in Paul Taylor’s diagrams package, from ≤1994, as mentioned in e.g. the changelog notes for v3.81 at http://www.paultaylor.eu/diagrams/ .  But it seems more likely that this was to meet the demand for a notation that was already established, rather than being the origin?  But looking at various well-known category theory textbooks from before 2000 (Mac Lane *Categories for the Working Mathematician*; Mac Lane and Moerdijk *Sheaves in Geometry and Logic*; Borceux *Handbook of Categorical Algebra*; Johnstone *Topos Theory*), none of them seem to use it, as far as I can find.

Comment: Have you asked at the Categories list?  I can imagine the answer would be known to someone like Freyd.

Comment: @ToddTrimble I strongly suspect it has been invented by him. I've seen it in several papers of Peter Freyd, as well as in [Cats and Allegators](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Categories,+Allegories). The latter is full of notation I wish would become standard, like puncture sign for non-commuting diagrams.

Comment: Indeed, the Freyd-Scedrov book from 1990 has the notation: https://books.google.com/books?id=fCSJRegkKdoC&pg=PA44&lpg=PA44&dq=freyd-scedrov+pullback&source=bl&ots=HCYDVjHb8n&sig=Q_BvUcvgUulhxC7N2EBtRi1GoE8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjcvp6_7_TSAhVDXD4KHUIsDDgQ6AEIITAB#v=onepage&q=freyd-scedrov%20pullback&f=false

Comment: @ToddTrimble: I originally drafted this question around a year ago for the categories list, but it was one of the periods when the moderator(s) were restricting discussion to very businesslike topics only, so I set the draft aside and forgot about it, until stumbling on it again today while searching for something else in my email.

Comment: While we're at it maybe we can standardize this notation too? I've seen that right angle all over the place and pointing in several different directions.

Comment: In Freyd's notation the corner is actually attached to the arrows.  He also seems to use a similar cross notation for products, and several other notations for (co)equalizers etc.

Comment: @JonathanBeardsley I thought it already was standard, as in the form discussed here, where the endpoints of the corner either touch or almost touch the pullback projection arrows.

Comment: @ToddTrimble: in some fields I agree this version is quite standard — certainly among people who self-identify as category theorists :-)  But I’ve seen various papers/books in homotopy theory (including quite recent ones) that place the corner-symbol differently — sometimes centred in the square, and sometimes even in the bottom-right corner of the square (but always still oriented as in the “standard” version, not the opposite orientation, which always afaik denotes a pushout/co-cartesian square).

Comment: Unfortunately, I think I have also seen the oppositely-oriented mark, in the upper-left corner of the square, used to denote a pullback rather than a pushout.  Don't remember where, though.

Comment: @MikeShulman: You can see such usage in Theorem 4.2 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.09050.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Mike was mentioning a case when a *pullback* (rether than pushout) was denoted by a wrong mark placed correctly, while in your reference it is *pushout* (rather than pullback) denoted by a mark that would be correct for pullback but placed elsewhere (in the lower right corner), I think it is not really misuse this way.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: The analogous notation for pushouts exists and places ⌜ in the lower right corner.
The cited paper uses the opposite corner.
Mike Shulman's question mentioned an “oppositely oriented mark” and my example certainly fits this part of his description.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: You can see the original notation in 1.565 of the above-cited book by Freyd and Scedrov.  The notation in the paper I cited uses the opposite corner.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov I agree with what you say. I only wanted to note that Mike mentions $\ulcorner$ in the upper-left corner used to denote pullback, while in your example, $\lrcorner$ in the lower right corner is used to denote pushout. (By the way, while the symbol for pushout should in any case sit in the lower right corner, it is not obvious it should be either $\ulcorner$ or $\lrcorner$ - to extend the analogy with mono-epi notations, it could be, say, $\backslash$...)

Comment: ...in fact one may argue that $\lrcorner$ might be even more appropriate than $\ulcorner$ from this point of view: to express that an arrow $\to$ is mono one adds an extra arrowhead $>$ at the source end, while to express that it is epi, one adds at the target end the same arrowhead, oriented the same way! So...

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: That's one point of view (i.e., a corner is an arrowhead).  Another point of view states that a corner is meant to represent the two newly constructed arrows; in the case of a pushout these two arrows give you ⌟.  And a third point of view states that a corner is meant to represent the two _old_ arrows, which would give you ⌜ for a pushout.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Interesting :D

Comment: I learned at a very young age to indicate that a diagram was a pullback by entering the letters "f.pr." (for "fiber product") in the center of the square. (This is a habit I've long since broken.)  I can no longer remember where I learned this.  I wonder if it's in any sense, or in any venue, standard.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In an email to me dated 17 February 1992, Peter Freyd said:

> I was using a different notation in 1974 in lectures at Montreal. A high school teacher named Butler suggested the right-angle. It was an improvement. I have used it since.

When the diagram gets too complicated for the pullbacks to be rectangles, such as in the final chapter of my book [*Practical Foundations of Mathematics*](http://www.paultaylor.eu/prafm), I strongly recommend making them at least *parallelograms*.  Then it is clear that pullback is acting as a functor that transforms one part of the diagram to another. In particular, in a type-theoretic setting pullback is *substitution*; whilst this has been known for a long time, Section 8.2 of the book actually proves it.

William Butler (had) proved some important results about monads, which you will find in "Toposes, Triples and Theories" by Barr and Wells ([free TAC reprints copy](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/12/tr12abs.html)).

Other very smart categorists who left academia to become schoolteachers include [Christian Mikkelsen](http://www.chrisjuul.dk/math/LL.pdf) (who was the first to derive colimits from limits in an elementary topos) and Sjoerd Crans (who did weak higher dimensional category theory).

Answer (score 15):

If it is of any use, on page 251 of Taylor's "Practical Foundations of Mathematics", shortly after introducing pullbacks, he writes:

> Pullbacks are often indicated with the right angle symbol, which was suggested by William Butler in 1974 and popularised by Peter Freyd.

Answer (score 4):

A small comment, that does not fit in its proper place. The department of Algebra in the University of Santiago de Compostela has studied categories since the second half of the sixties under the leadership of prof. Eduardo García-Rodeja. I made my studies later and the following notations were standard:

• Cartesian square:

[image]

• coCartesian square:

[image]

So, I was not surprised to see Paul Taylor's notation. And for me, too, it was the first time I noticed a notation similar to the one it was used here in print. later, the main research areas where closed categories and homology theories, though after all these years, it has diversified a lot.

Comment: Very interesting, thankyou!  What was your department then, and who were the people who you saw using this — either in terms of individuals, or in terms of what research area(s) they were in?

Comment: I'va added some precisions. For me, personally, it was very useful to have a good background in categories  to study cohomology in algebraic geometry.